# Trying to create a HTML Mailto form for vacation request, but I can not get it to work.

Tags: mailto

This is what I've got so far. (Email address is of course not the real one) But I must have lapsed on how to do this. I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to send the info to an email address. Can anyone help me finish this?

```
<h2>Vacation Request</h2>

<form action="mailto:test@test.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
<form>
Start Date<br>
<input id="date" type="date">
</form>
<form>
End Date<br>
<input id="date" type="date">
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you will need to use some server side technology like PHP to make this work. You cannot send an email from the plain HTML

Comment: Any idea how I can do this? I'm trying to create it for my boss as a way for notoriety.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp First create PHP script on backend, implement sending email and then add script path to form's action attribute.